# Observe optional

Tags: swift, option-type, rx-swift

I am very new in RxSwift so question maybe a little strange: 
I need to observe change in UIWebView.request.
At first it is nil so need to catch when it get any assign.
I tried:

```
myWebView.rx.observe(URLRequest.self, #keyPath(UIWebView.request)
.subscribe {
print ($0)
}
```

Nothing. Got at first next(nil). and never call it again.

I tried:

```
myWebView.rx.observe(URLRequest.self, #keyPath(RUIWebView.request), options: [.new, .initial], retainSelf: true)
```

Also nothing.

thanks.

Comment: Is `request` KVO observable? If not then key path observing will likely not work and give you the described behaviour.

Comment: UIWebView is deprecated since iOS 8. Use WKWebView.

Comment: so if it is not KVO, there is no ability to observe ?

Comment: @the4kman WKWebView dont have same ability as UIWebView, for example load external fonts.

Comment: @EugeneDon nope, keys that are not KVO compliant are not guaranteed to work. They might, or might not (as it happens with a lot of UIKit properties)

Comment: @EugeneDon [WKWebView can load external fonts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785179/using-custom-fonts-in-wkwebview)

Comment: Here'a question that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40371573/1974224

Comment: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxWebKit